# Change the time format

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a function called CalDateShow which returns the output as "Feb 29 (Wed) 16:30 -  17:30".
The input parameters are passed to that function is given below.
The input parameters are generated on clicking a particular cell of a calendar.

startday= Wed Feb 29 2012 16:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

endday = Wed Feb 29 2012 17:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

```
function CalDateShow(startday, endday, isshowtime, isshowweek) {
        if (!endday) {
            return dateFormat.call(startday, getymformat(startday,null,isshowtime));
        } else {
            var strstart= dateFormat.call(startday, getymformat(startday, null, isshowtime, isshowweek));
            var strend=dateFormat.call(endday, getymformat(endday, startday, isshowtime, isshowweek));
            var join = (strend!=""? " - ":"");
            return [strstart,strend].join(join);
        }
    }
```

I want to change the output to Feb 29 (Wed) 4:30 pm -  5:30 pm.
Any help would be appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve what you need to using the built in datetime object:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

This library also has some nice datetime formatting functionality with it:
http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/